# How to Converting string 'Tue, 07 Dec 2021 04:35:05 GMT' to smalldatetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) in sql server

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, sql-server-2012, sqldb

I have string 'Tue, 07 Dec 2021 04:35:05 GMT' and i need to convert to smalldatetime format like '2021-12-07 04:35:05'(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) in sql server. please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have code that converts datetimes to non-ISO 8601 format from the start? (Don't answer this, just consider correcting this somewhere else.)

Comment: This makes me think you're making one of two very big mistakes. Either 1) you're formatting DateTime values for storage in a varchar column (_NEVER_ do that; always use DateTime/DateTime2/etc for your date values) or you're trying to use string concatenation instead of parameterized queries to build your SQL, which... eww. That's the fast way to get your app hacked.

Comment: You have a fine collection of tags there. Are you writing this code in spark and it's being pushed to SQL Server? Where will this code be written?

Answer (score 0):

If you truncate the day name and the timezone from the value, and you're using an English based language, this works. I *assume* your value is always in the format `ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tz`:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, SUBSTRING('Tue, 07 Dec 2021 04:35:05 GMT',6,20);
```

Note that `smalldatetime` is accurate to 1 minute, so the seconds precision will be lost. So, for your value, `2021-12-07 04:35:00` would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that the datetime string isn't only in the GMT timezone.
And if you'd like to have a small datetime in a fixed timezone.

Here's a demo that makes use of a reference table.

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table ref_timezones (
>  tz_code varchar(8) primary key, 
>  tz_offset char(6) not null check (tz_offset like '[+-][01][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]'), 
>  name varchar(30)
> );
>
> insert into ref_timezones (
> tz_code, 
> tz_offset
> ) values
> ('CDT',  '-05:00'),
> ('EST',  '-05:00'),
> ('Z',    '+00:00'),
> ('GMT',  '+00:00'),
> ('+00:00', '+00:00'),
> ('CET',  '+01:00'),
> ('CEST', '+02:00'), 
> ('ACDT', '+10:30');
>
> create table test (col varchar(30));
> insert into test (col) values
>   ('Tue, 07 Dec 2021 04:35:05 GMT')
> , ('Wed, 08 Dec 2021 05:46:36 CEST')
> ```

**Query**

> ```
> SELECT col
> , TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(col,6,20) AS DATETIME) AS dt_no_offset
> , CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(
>     TRY_CAST(
>       SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', col), 21)
>     + COALESCE(tz.tz_offset, '+00:00')
>     AS DATETIMEOFFSET(0)), '+00:00') AS SMALLDATETIME) AS small_dt_at_zulu
> FROM test
> OUTER APPLY (
>    SELECT tz_offset
>    FROM ref_timezones 
>    WHERE tz_code = RIGHT(col, PATINDEX('%_[ ][0-9][0-9]:%', REVERSE(col)))
> ) tz;
> ```

| col | dt_no_offset | small_dt_at_zulu |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tue, 07 Dec 2021 04:35:05 GMT | 2021-12-07 04:35:05.000 | 2021-12-07 04:35 |
| Wed, 08 Dec 2021 05:46:36 CEST | 2021-12-08 05:46:36.000 | 2021-12-08 03:47 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c34e9f83ec5c3c85ca73d6984e352a0b)*